# swap coordinates in numpy 3d array

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array with shape (3,10,10).
How can I change the array such that the first coordinate (column) will be the last, and the last will be the first (e.g. the shape of the array will be (10, 10, 3))?
I tried:

```
arr.flatten().reshape((10,10,3))
```

Is there a more elegant/efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use transpose function with axes parameter:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>x = np.ones((3,10,10))
>>>tx = np.transpose(x, (2, 1, 0))
>>>tx.shape
(10, 10, 3)
```

Comment: thanks! just curious, is the result supposed to be different than arr.flatten().reshape((10,10,3)) ?

Comment: Yes it is.
Here is my demonstration:
x = np.array([[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]],[[5],[6]]])
x.shape is ==> (3, 2, 1)

np.transpose(x, (2, 1, 0)) would look like:
array([[[1, 3, 5],
        [2, 4, 6]]])

And
x.flatten().reshape((1,2,3)) would result in:
array([[[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6]]])